# Simple dB to perceived loudness chart

Tags: homework-and-exercises, acoustics, units

I've read that an increase in $10\, \mathrm{dB}$ results in a doubling of the perceived loudness.
Given that, is my table below correct?

| dB | perceived loudness |
| --- | --- |
| 130 | 8192 |
| 120 | 4096 |
| 110 | 2048 |
| 100 | 1024 |
| 90 | 512 |
| 80 | 256 |
| 70 | 128 |
| 60 | 64 |
| 50 | 32 |
| 40 | 16 |
| 30 | 8 |
| 20 | 4 |
| 10 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 |